# this.props.location.pathname for dynamic URLs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

If you have URLs in your app that can change (e.g `/profile/1` and `/profile/2`, how do you access that from `this.props.location.pathname`?

In my `Profile` component I have a `componentDidMount` method like so:

```
componentDidMount () {
    if (this.props.location.pathname === 'profile/:id/') {
      console.log('is profile')
  } else {
      console.log('is not profile')
  }
}
```

Which returns `is not profile` when I'm on the profile pages.

The project I'm using uses [react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) as a base (not sure if that helps), which uses react-router-v3.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
import { matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

if (matchPath(this.props.location.pathname, { path: 'profile/:id' })) {}
```

Or

```
this.props.match.path === 'profile/:id'
```

I'm not sure why your `Profile` component gets mounted if it's not a profile though.

Answer (score 3):

`if (this.props.location.pathname === 'profile/:id/')`

this will never be true because of `:id` is a matcher:

try:

`if (this.props.match.params.id)`

This way you will check if there's `id` parameter in current route.

https://jaketrent.com/post/access-route-params-react-router-v4/

Comment: Sorry Tomasz, should've clarified I'm using react-router ^3.0.0

Comment: @A7DC I think it's the same.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, didn't work for me but lead me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

With React hooks you can do something like this

```
import {Route, useRouteMatch} from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
    const match = useRouteMatch("match/this/route/:id")
    return (
        //suppose you dont want to show navbar in this route
        {match && match.path === 'match/this/route/:id' ? <SomeComponent/> : <Navbar/>}
    )}
//match.path check for the dynamic route match/this/route/:id
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't feel like the best way to do this, but it worked for me:

`this.props.location.pathname === '/profile/' + this.props.params.id`

Answer (score 0):

use match props to get dynamic path

```
componentDidMount () {
  if (this.props.match.path === 'profile/:id') {
    console.log('is profile')
  } else {
    console.log('is not profile')
  }
}
```

refer this for more information [react-redux-match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match)